# Spartacus Promotion Service getProductPromotionForEntry

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Im using Spartacus 1.5 version and used the promotionService.getProductPromotionForEntry in the cart page. I have a appliedPromotion for my item but it will return empty array. may I know what is to consider to have a applied promotions?

Comment: Hi rayss. Just make sure your promotion is properly configured in backoffice and enabled. With this, the OCC call should return the promotion. Have a look at the promotions docs in help.sap.com

Comment: thanks, i will check it out.